# Grub Menu not showing what to do?

Tags: grub2, grub-efi

I have  HP desk G3 400 mini and i forgot the password and i am not able to reset it through the grub menu because i never am able to get during the boot, if i try using the terminal its asking me the password for any command i give in. the only start up menu i get is hp start up menu and ive done everything putting the order of the ubuntu in the boot option and i still cant seem to show it the grub menu. is there any way i could factoy reset or remove ubutnu or installed another OS without having it to use password??? can i get ubuntu live chat support somehow?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I reset a lost administrative password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password)

Comment: There is no live chat support.

Comment: There are many support sites; text change exists on Stack Exchange (*here, but you can't use your Ubuntu SSO signon if you're using that; it requires Stack Exchange login*), IRC (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/IRC/ChannelList), Telegram, Matrix & more...